# Java classes are not on classpath and cannot be found by scanner

Tags: java, classpath

I have a Gradle project which has a dependency on a module (another Gradle task):

```
ProjectA
- com/myapp/MyApp
```

and

```
ModuleA
- com/infra/SomeCode.java
- com/infra/CustomGradleTask.java
```

`CustomGradleTask.java`:

```
public class CustomGradleTask implements Plugin<Project> {

  @Override
  public void apply(Project project) {

    TaskContainer taskContainer = project.getTasks();

    taskContainer.register("validateClasses", SomeCode.class);
    taskContainer.findByPath("build").finalizedBy("CustomTask");
  }
}
```

`SomeCode.java`:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.myapp", new ResourcesScanner());
Set<String> resources = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.class"));
```

However `resources` size is 0.

Why are the java classes inside `ProjectA` not being found?

I can find classes inside `ModuleA`, but not `ProjectA`

Comment: You mentioned Scanner in the title of your question, and yet there seem to be no Scanner in your code. Also, what does Scanner have to do with the classpath?

Comment: I'm using Java `Reflections` library to scan the classpath for certain classes .. it finds no results